# Which is the most reliable scaffolding structure for developing a angularjs app with typescript and TDD

Tags: angularjs, typescript, scaffolding

I'm learning to develop an application using Angular JS with Typescript using TDD approach. I wanted to know on what factors should we consider the basic scaffolding structure or seed project (whether considering testing framework or build system like gulp, grunt etc). 
Is there a tutorial on creating this structure on ourselves.

Comment: avoid sock drawer organization. here are good options:

http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a NodeJs/Express backend. I'd stick to some structure like this.

1 - Remember to separate concerns. At one side the backend, in the other the front-end. 
2 - Try to keep a clean Model View Controller in your ExpressJS Project.
3 - In your Angular App try to follow a good OOP design using TypeScript. 
4 - Make your test as real as possible. When they start to be a bit slow Stub your HTTP requests.

Hope it helps!

```
FOLDERS
>root
-> start.ts
-> backend
--> configs
--> controllers
--> models
--> routes
--> services
--> tests (Mocha tests)

-> typings
-> scss
-> public
--> images
--> css
--> cache_manifests
--> frontEnd
---> project1
-----> tests
-----> components
-----> configs
-----> models
-----> services
-----> app.module.ts
-----> app.ts
-----> etc...
---> project2
---> project3
```

GULP SCRIPT

```
gulp.task("dev:build", function () {
  var tsProject = ts.createProject(path.resolve("./tsconfig.json"));
  var tsResult = gulp.src([
    "**/*.ts",
    "!typings/**/*.ts"
  ]).
    pipe(sourcemaps.init()).
    pipe(tsProject());

  return tsResult.js.
    pipe(sourcemaps.write()).
    pipe(gulp.dest(path.resolve("./")));
});
```

EXCELLENT TUTORIAL: https://angular.io/

It has all about TDD on Angular2. Take your time to read it.